# Naturally ORDER a column containing hierarchical item names

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column (of VARCHAR type) with values like these:

```
1
2
3
1.1
1.1.1
1.2.1
5
4
7
8
9
10
10.2
10.1
```

I hop[e to select this column and order it naturally, like the following:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.2.1
2
3
4
5
...
```

I have tried ordering it with this for example and a lot of other query

```
SELECT data 
FROM sample 
ORDER BY LEN(data), data
```

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You've tagged this for both MySQL and MS SQL Server. Please edit your question to eliminate one of the tags, unless you want answers for both server products.

Comment: i have edit my question to tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hoping to order a series of hierarchically named items in a natural order. It looks like these items' names take the form.

```
 token [ .token [. token [ .token ]]]
```

where subsequent tokens after the first are optional.

I suppose you want each token, if it's numeric, to be handed as a number.  That is, for example, you want `1.123` to come after `1.2` because `123` is numerically greater than `2`.

You didn't say what you want done with alphabetical tokens, e.g. `401.k` and `403.b`. I suppose they should come after the numerical ones, but in lexical order.

This query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81756/2/0) will do the trick out to five hierarchical levels of tokens.

```
SELECT col
  FROM T 
 ORDER BY
       FLOOR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',1)),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',1),

       FLOOR(SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',1)))),
       SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',1))),

       FLOOR(SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',2)))),
       SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',2))),

       FLOOR(SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',3)))),
       SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',3))),

       FLOOR(SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',4)))),
       SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',4)))
```

Why does this work? `FLOOR()` converts the leftmost part of a string to an integer, so it picks up the leading integer.  If it doesn't find any numbers in the string it's trying to convert, it returns zero.

And, `SUBSTRING(col, 2+LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',NNN)))` picks up the part of the `col` item to the right of the `NNN`th dot.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. that is what i need.. great answer and explanation. +1

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   ORDER BY data, LEN(data)
```

or this

```
 ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ',', -1), SIGNED), Len(data)
```

i give demo in mysql as tsql there is not in sqfiddle .

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd6e/7)

Comment: short and effective answer. that did it the trick.. thank you very much.. +1

Answer (score 1):

The data seems something like Hierarchical. With the current set of data supplied, if data is converted to hierarchical Data the order by can be done using something similar to:-

> SELECT data  FROM sample  ORDER BY CAST ( '/' + replace( data, '.',
>   '/' ) + '/'  as hierarchyid )